# How to send multiple request/users in each tenant under multi-tenant system using Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant system where multiple users are hitting requests in each tenant . Can anyone tell me how to do this using jmeter.

Scenario : 10 tenants available and in each tenant 10 users are sent which are hitting some requests , I dont know how to send multiple different users in each separate tenant using application URl.

Comment: It sounds like a Stresstest. For stress testing endpoints i recommend gatling, which you can find here https://gatling.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clean what you're asking. If each virtual user needs to execute the same set of actions in different tenants you could do the following:

1. Create a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) holding virtual user steps
2. Use [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)(s) where required to avoid code duplication for each tenant
3. The tenant URLs can be parameterised using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, actually there is project requirement where i am not sure like each tenant will be having different url or if it is having one single application url then how will i access each tenant by using application url.